# reprojectImageTo3D gives unexpected real world coordinates

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV with two identical webcams to reconstruct the real world coordinates. The cameras are calibrated using chessboards and I typed the parameters in as constants. The rectified images seem acceptable to me: http://postimg.org/image/ccj5c2swt/ Then I use reprojectImageTo3D() function with calculated Q matrix and the disparity map to obtain the real world coordinate while clicking on different positions on the disparity map. However, the result z coordinates are hard to understand: http://postimg.org/image/e326dkafx/ and when if click on certain positions, the program will crash. Below is my complete code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.hpp"
#include "cxcore.hpp"
#include "cvaux.hpp"
#include "math.h"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;

static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*);

Mat xyz;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{           
    Mat img_l = imread("recl1.png", 1);
    Mat img_r = imread("recr1.png", 1);

    //initialize camera parameters
    double camera_matrix_left[] = { 650.90584, 0, 308.65233,
        0, 648.69669, 251.15348,
        0, 0, 1 };
    double camera_matrix_right[] = { 651.50089, 0, 308.65391,
        0, 649.74142, 264.51927,
        0, 0, 1 };
    double dist_coeffs_left[] = { -0.10965, 0.02291, 0.00306, 0.00067,0,0,0,-1.12 };
    double dist_coeffs_right[] = { -0.09781, 0.12686, 0.00837, 0.00167,0,0,0,-2.04 };
    double rot_vector[] = { 0.01605, 0.00785, -0.02446 };
    double rot_matrix[] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    double translation[] = { -65.81781, -0.13752, 2.75072 };

    Mat _M1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, camera_matrix_left);
    Mat _M2 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, camera_matrix_right);
    Mat _D1 = Mat(1, 8, CV_64FC1, dist_coeffs_left);
    Mat _D2 = Mat(1, 8, CV_64FC1, dist_coeffs_right);
    Size imageSize = img_l.size();
    Mat _R_vector = Mat(3, 1, CV_64FC1, rot_vector);
    Mat _R_matrix = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, rot_matrix);
    Mat _T = Mat(3, 1, CV_64FC1, translation);
    //Bouguet's method for rectification

    Mat _R1, _R2, _P1, _P2, Q, mx1, my1, mx2, my2, imgl_rec, imgr_rec;
    Rect roi1, roi2;

    stereoRectify(_M1, _D1, _M2, _D2, imageSize, _R_matrix, _T, _R1, _R2, _P1, _P2, Q, CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, -1, imageSize, &roi1, &roi2);

    Q.at<double>(3, 2) = -Q.at<double>(3, 2);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(_M1, _D1, _R1, _P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, mx1, my1);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(_M1, _D1, _R1, _P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, mx2, my2);

    //rectify input images
    remap(img_l, imgl_rec, mx1, my1, INTER_LINEAR);
    remap(img_r, imgr_rec, mx2, my2, INTER_LINEAR);

    Mat rec_pair = Mat(imgl_rec.rows, imgl_rec.cols * 2, imgl_rec.type());
    imgl_rec.copyTo(rec_pair(Rect(0, 0, imgl_rec.cols, imgl_rec.rows)));
    imgr_rec.copyTo(rec_pair(Rect(imgl_rec.cols, 0, imgr_rec.cols, imgr_rec.rows)));

    for (int i = 0; i < rec_pair.rows; i += 32) line(rec_pair, Point(0, i), Point(rec_pair.cols, i), Scalar(0, 0, 255));

    namedWindow("Rectified", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Rectified", rec_pair);
    //cvWaitKey(0);

    //Setup for finding stereo corrrespondences
    int SADWindowSize = 0, numberOfDisparities = 0;
    StereoSGBM sgbm;
    StereoBM bm;
    sgbm.preFilterCap = 63;
    sgbm.SADWindowSize = SADWindowSize > 0 ? SADWindowSize : 3;

    numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities > 0 ? numberOfDisparities : ((imageSize.width / 8) + 15) & -16;

    bm.state->roi1 = roi1;
    bm.state->roi2 = roi2;
    bm.state->preFilterCap = 31;
    bm.state->SADWindowSize = SADWindowSize > 0 ? SADWindowSize : 9;
    bm.state->minDisparity = 0;
    bm.state->numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities;
    bm.state->textureThreshold = 10;
    bm.state->uniquenessRatio = 15;
    bm.state->speckleWindowSize = 100;
    bm.state->speckleRange = 32;
    bm.state->disp12MaxDiff = 1;

    enum { STEREO_BM = 0, STEREO_SGBM = 1, STEREO_HH = 2, STEREO_VAR = 3 };
    int cn = imgl_rec.channels();
    int alg = STEREO_SGBM;
    sgbm.P1 = 8 * cn*sgbm.SADWindowSize*sgbm.SADWindowSize;
    sgbm.P2 = 32 * cn*sgbm.SADWindowSize*sgbm.SADWindowSize;
    sgbm.minDisparity = 0;
    sgbm.numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities;
    sgbm.uniquenessRatio = 30;
    sgbm.speckleWindowSize = bm.state->speckleWindowSize;
    sgbm.speckleRange = bm.state->speckleRange;
    sgbm.disp12MaxDiff = 1;
    sgbm.fullDP = alg == STEREO_HH;

    //solve disparity graph
    Mat disp, disp8;
    int64 t = getTickCount();
    sgbm(imgl_rec, imgr_rec, disp);
    t = getTickCount() - t;
    printf("Disparity obtained. Time elapsed: %fms\n", t * 1000 / getTickFrequency());
    disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8U, 255 / (numberOfDisparities*16.));
    namedWindow("disparity", 0);
    imshow("disparity", disp8);

    reprojectImageTo3D(disp, xyz, Q, true, CV_32F);

    setMouseCallback("disparity", onMouse, 0);
    while (1){
        int c = waitKey(0);
        if ((char)c == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        Point3f p = xyz.at<Point3f>(x, y);
        printf("point <%d, %d> in world coordinate: x=%.2f y=%.2f z=%.2f\n", x, y, p.x, p.y, p.z);
    }
}
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Now I checked the values in the matrices calculated by stereoRectify() function. Below are the result

```
R1:
1.00    0.00    -0.04  
-0.00   1.00    0.00  
0.04    0.00    1.00  
P1:  
621.65  0.00    343.70  
0.00    0.00    621.65  
255.82  0.00    0.00  
0.00    1.00    0.00  
R2:  
1.00    0.00    -0.04  
-0.00   1.00    0.00  
0.04    0.00    1.00  
P2:  
621.65  0.00    343.70  
-40951.56       0.00    621.65  
255.82  0.00    0.00  
0.00    1.00    0.00  
Q:  
1.00    0.00    0.00    -343.70  
0.00    1.00    0.00    -255.82  
0.00    0.00    0.00    621.65  
0.00    0.00    -0.02   -0.00
```

I think there might be something wrong with these matrices, especially the Q matrix.